# How to play MIDI instrument at arbitrary pitch

Tags: sound

With `SoundNote`, one can play specific semitones using numerous styles, such as `Piano`, `Flute`, `Bird`, etc., but it doesn't seem that one can play arbitrary frequencies - just ones that match semitones.

With `AudioGenerator`, one can easily specify frequency but one has limited sound style options.

How can I play arbitrary frequencies with arbitrary styles?

Comment: Could you use `AudioFrequencyShift` to adjust the pitch from the nearest semitone?

Comment: With MIDI, the normal way to do this is to use the MIDI pitchbend command. Unfortunately, SoundNote does not appear to support any kind of pitch bend.